# Getting ElasticNet weight estimates

Tags: scikit-learn, regularization, elastic-net

Regarding Zou and Hastie (2005), they formulate an augmented problem with $(X^*, y^*, \lambda_1, \lambda_2)$, which they they say can be used in a lasso-type problem where $\alpha = \frac{\lambda_1}{\sqrt(1 + \lambda_2)}$. However, when you read about how most people solve the elastic net optimization problem, they take about LARS or gradient descent methods. What is the difference between simply putting $X^*, y^*, \alpha$ through some lasso solver in `sklearn` versus using LARS or gradient descent?